# using arg vector in fopen

Tags: c, file-io

I wish to have a file name as an argument to the C program. I tried all the possible ways in `fopen` something like the below.

```
fp = fopen(*argv[2], "r");
```

Also used `"*argv[2]"` but did not work. I want to know where I am going wrong so that I can use this correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

```
fp = fopen(argv[2], "r");
```

Please be aware that `argv[0]` will contain your exe name(with path), other arguments which you pass will start from `argv[1]`.

Refer to [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson14.html) for more details on using command line arguments in C.

In your main function if you are getting `char **argv` as the argument, the array subscripting `argv[1]` automatically turns it into a `char *` which is expected as an argument by fopen.

Comment: +1, it would help to explain that the array subscripting (e.g. `x[1]`) is what takes the `char**` to the `char*` needed.

Answer (score 3):

```
fp = fopen(argv[2], "r" )
```

is enough

argv is an array of character pointers. Indexing this array gives you the strings you've passed on the command line. You don't need further dereferencing with an additional `*`

Answer (score 1):

[fopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) takes a char* as argument for the filename:

> FILE *fopen(const char *path, const char *mode);

You just need to use it like:

```
fp = fopen(argv[2], "r"); // if 2nd argument passed is your filename
```